# Show that the disk-algebra, equipped with the involution $f^*(z) = \overline {f(\overline z)}$ is a Banach-*-algebra.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I am working from Anton Deitmar's "Principles of Harmonic Analysis" and in one of the exercises he asks to show that the disk-algebra, equipped with the involution $$f^*(z) = \overline {f(\overline z)}$$ is a Banach-*-algebra. I have done the other part of the question but I am unsure how I would tackle this section.

The part I am stuck on is this:

$||f||=sup\{|f(z)|\ \Big|z\in\mathbb D\}$

$||f^*||=sup\{|f^*(z)|\ \Big|z\in\mathbb D\}=sup\{|\overline {f(\overline z)}|\ \Big|z\in\mathbb D\}$

So I guess I want to show that $sup\{|f(z)|\ \Big|z\in\mathbb D\}=sup\{|\overline {f(\overline z)}|\ \Big|z\in\mathbb D\}$ which I feel may be obvious but I cannot see why.

Comment: You shouldn't delete questions after you get partial answers in the comments: [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197692/show-that-the-disk-algebra-equipped-with-the-involution-f∗z-fz-is-a-bana)

Comment: Sorry I realised that I had completely messed up the question by not including the bars in the involution so I thought that this would be clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that if $w=\overline{z}$, then $|f(z)|=|\overline{f(z)}|=|\overline{f(\overline{w})}|$.  So the set of possible values of $|f(z)|$ is exactly the same as the set of possible values of $|\overline{f(\overline{z})}|$.